# scope javascript script tag

Tags: jquery, scope

My knowledge of javascript is rather limited.
I'm using jquery in a main page. This page loads the content from a div using a jquery call to the server.
This loaded content in turn uses jquery.
However I noticed that I have to include the jquery javascript file in each load I do(so in the content that is loaded in the div I have to put the script tag again).
This is rather error prone.
I would think that it is possible to load a js globally so it can be used in all divs(even the ones that are loaded later on).
Maybe I'm just missing something here.

Is the way I do it how it should be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not do it in the server side? like using server side languages to include jquery

Comment: can you add some code? like, the code you include is for example `$('#a').click(...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are making ajax call to another page which is also using jquery ,if it is so then you need to add jquery file in both the pages

Comment: Yes I make an ajax call to another php page. The content of that call is then shown in a div. The returned content uses jquery as well. So if I understand correct: I just have to include the <script> tag for all page that get loaded this way. (so I'm doing this as it should be done/no other better way to fix this).

Comment: even though you are displaying in a div of same page ,but the content to be dispalyed is prepared by another php page only right so you should add jquery in that page also